# The solution found by the optimization function when exitflag is negative

Tags: matlab, constrained-optimization

I'm using Matlab's fmincon to solve a constrained nonlinear optimization for varying sets of parameters in the objective function. I have 2 parameters and have 400 unique combination of these 2 parameters. Within a particular combination of parameters I use a range of start points (100 start points). Trying to do rough simulation of multi-start functionality using optimization toolbox.

For a given combination of parameters in objective function, majority of the start points would solve the optimization problem and [exit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/exit-flags-and-exit-messages.html) with a positive exitflag like 1 and in some cases 2. But for very small number of cases, the program would finish with an exitflag of -3 which corresponds to [*objective function at current iteration went below options.ObjectiveLimit and maximum constraint violation was less than options.TolCon.*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html). In such cases, the output message mentions about problem might be unbounded. One example message is below

> Problem appears unbounded.
>
> fmincon stopped because the objective function value is less than
>   the default value of the objective function limit and constraints 
>   are satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.
>
> Stopping criteria details:
>
> fmincon stopped because the objective function value, -5.374294e+40, is less than
>   options.ObjectiveLimit = -1.000000e+20, and the relative maximum constraint
>   violation, 0.000000e+00, is less than options.TolCon = 1.000000e-06.
>
> Optimization Metric                                         Options
>   objective value =  -5.37e+40               ObjectiveLimit =  -1e+20 (default)
>   relative max(constraint violation) =   0.00e+00    TolCon =   1e-06 (default)

Here are my questions: -

a) If the problem was able to find local minima for certain start points (as indicated by exitflag 1) within a particular combination of parameters, why does few other start points mention about problem being "unbounded" (exitflag -3).

b) When the exitflag is -3, the objective function value returned by fmincon does NOT match the explicit calculation of function value at the x point returned by fmincon. Matlab link on [Current Point and Function value](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/current-point-and-function-value.html) mentions "The function value is the value of the objective function at the current point." which does not state restriction on exitflags. On the other hand, [Output Arguments](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/function-arguments.html) states this for x "The solution found by the optimization function. If exitflag > 0, then x is a solution; otherwise, x is the value of the optimization routine when it terminated prematurely." possibly implying that if exitflag is negative then *The function value is NOT the value of the objective function at the current point.* I'm not sure whether it is inconsistent documentation or a mis-interpretation on my part?

Lastly, will draw attention to the statement [Exit flags are not infallible guides to the quality of a solution. Many other factors, such as tolerance settings, can affect whether a solution is satisfactory to you. You are responsible for deciding whether a solver returns a satisfactory answer. Sometimes a negative exit flag does not correspond to a "bad" solution. Similarly, sometimes a positive exit flag does not correspond to a "good" solution.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/exit-flags-and-exit-messages.html). I can understand +ve exitflags not being necessarily good in all scenarios, but why would a negative exitflag not necessarily mean a "bad" solution?

Comment: Have you examined the solution returned by fmincon?  Does it satisfy your constraints?  Is its objective function value really -5.4e+40?

Comment: Is your optimization problem actually unbounded but you want to find a local minimum point?

Comment: @Brian (responding to 1st comment) - The objective function value is NOT -5.4e+40 and that is why I posed question b). The point x returned at exit of program when substituted in to objective function does not produce the function value returned by fmincon. (Do note, that the point x returned by fmincon does satisfy the constraints).

Comment: There's likely a bug in your code that evaluates the objective function then.

Comment: The objective function handle that I pass to fmincon is the same objective function that I use post the completion of fmincon to substitute the optimal x and compare with optimal function value. It is internally consistent. Could this be floating point issue? or as I mentioned in point b of my question could it be possible that when exitflag is negative, the optimal x returned and the optimal function value are not same

Comment: A simple way to debug this would be to modify your objective function so that it outputs the offending parameters and issues an error whenever it computes a very large negative value (anything less than -1.0e20.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found the list of issue(s) though don't understand why. I notice computation difference between using matlabFunction to evaluate a function at specific point versus using subs/double on a symbolic expression for the same point. They do not match. Are there any documented references regarding such differences? (Btw, the question I raised in point b is resolved. When exitflag is -ve the function value is the value of Obj func at current point).